# Word size mul in Assembly

Tags: assembly, cpu-word, nasm

I'm making a subroutine for a factorial operation. All of my local variables are in word size since I'm using stack for pass-by-value.

```
[ebp+4] is the counter/decrementing multiplier
[ebp-2] is the multiplicand
```

Currently, I have this code block like this:

```
while1:

    cmp byte[ebp+4], 1
    je exit1
    dec word[ebp+4]
    mov ax, [ebp-2]
    mov dx, 0
    mul byte[ebp+4]
    mov word[ebp-2], ax

    jmp while1
```

And it has these following input and output results:

```
1 -> 02561
2 -> 2
3 -> 6
4 -> 24
5 -> 120
6 -> 208
7 -> 176
8 -> 128
```

It's only correct from 2 to 5. I realized that I'm making a byte-sized multiplication because of `mul byte[ebp+4]`, thus, hindering the result of 6! = 720.
So I changed `mul byte[ebp+4]` to `mul word[ebp+4]`:

```
while1:

    cmp byte[ebp+4], 1
    je exit1
    dec word[ebp+4]
    mov ax, [ebp-2]
    mov dx, 0
    mul word[ebp+4]
    mov word[ebp-2], ax

    jmp while1
```

It then has these following input and output results:

```
1 -> 02561
2 -> 07682
3 -> 28166
4 -> 62488
5 -> 46200
6 -> 60112
7 -> 35760
8 -> 15744
```

What am I doing wrong? I already cleared in the *dx* before the *mul* operation, but why is it not functioning properly?

Note: I have the correct printing routine of a word-size variable to 5 characters in ASCII for stdout. Also, I have a special case of 0! done in *cmp* before the iteration code block.

Im using Ubuntu 13 x86 and NASM.

---

update. here's the code block right on top of the *while1*:

```
fact: 

    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 2
    mov ax, [ebp+4]
    mov word[ebp-2], ax

    ; checks if num is zero
    cmp byte[ebp+4], 0
    je one
```

Comment: When you changed it to handle words, could you please show your complete updated while loop? You'd need to make changes in a couple of places and it's not clear from your description what you did.

Comment: @mbratch updated it. Sorry about that. The only line that changed was the mul byte[ebp+4] to mul word[ebp+4].

Comment: Did you change the code (which you're not showing) that initializes the value of `word[ebp+4]` so that it's `word` not `byte`? Also, `cmp byte[ebp+4], 1` should be `cmp word[epb+4], 1` but that isn't causing your current problem.

Comment: @mbratch I updated the post again by putting in the code block before the while1. I noticed that if I made cmp word[epb+4], 1 instead of cmp byte[ebp+4], 1 it doesn't go in the je even if it is one. So I used the byte instead.

Comment: If `cmp word[ebp+4], 1` isn't working, that indicates that what's at `word[ebp+4]` may not be what you expect or what it should be. The upper byte of the word is evidently not 0. Using the byte compare instead is covering up an issue somewhere.

Comment: @mbratch Whoooaaa!!! thanks dude!!! This is what happened: I had a word-sized num variable from the _start and then it ate the carriage return of my stdin. I clipped my input by having a second buffer during stdin. That solved it! :D

Comment: Put in answer so I can give you rep! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `cmp word[ebp+4], 1` isn't working, that indicates that what's at word[ebp+4] may not be what you expect or what it should be. The upper byte of the word is evidently not `0`. Using the byte compare instead is covering up an issue somewhere. So you'll need to examine what's happening with the word at that location.